# How to use latitude and longitude data in state space models in r?

Tags: r, time-series, spatial, state-space-models

Question on using latitude and longitude data in state space models in r: I have ecological data gathered over multiple years, including counts of animals (divided by male/female/young) and latitude and longitude coordinates for each observation. Do I need to divide these latitude longitude coordinates up into regions or zones in order to track the same area through time? My ultimate goal is to create and analyze competing models used to predict population trends/demographics.

Comment: Check out this CRAN task view for [spatial analysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html)  and this resource from [Duke](https://guides.library.duke.edu/r-geospatial) and this resource on [species modeling](https://rspatial.org/raster/sdm/)